# ME function and margin Function from twopm package rstudio

Tags: r

I ran my twopart model and I have tried following the but the margins and the AME commands to get the marginal effects on all the variables, but I am running into a really weird issue with the data frame for some reason.

```
> margin(tpmodel1)
Error in `[.data.frame`(newdata, , term) : undefined columns selected
```

But when looking at the guide for the twopm package, it says that all I need to do is just `AME(tpmodel1)` or `margin(tpmodel1)` to get all the marginal effects and it is still giving that error. so then i did

```
> margin(tpmodel1, newdata = NULL, term = NULL, se=TRUE)
Error in `[.data.frame`(newdata, , term) : undefined columns selected
```

And

```
 > margin(tpmodel1, newdata = dfasthma, term = NULL, se=TRUE)
Error in margin(tpmodel1, newdata = dfasthma, term = NULL, se = TRUE) :
```

some of independent variables of the two-part model are not available in the newdata set

of which doesnt make sense cause The data set i created for the variables I am using is dfasthma.

the code from the package:

```
margin(object, newdata = NULL, term = NULL, value = NULL,
se = TRUE, se.method = c("delta","bootstrap"), CI = TRUE, CI.boots = FALSE,
level = 0.95,eps = 1e-7,na.action = na.pass, iter = 50)
```

The image attached is a guide to the margin command from the package

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please read and incorporate elements from [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1082435). Especially the aspects of using `dput()` for the input and then an explicit example of your expected dataset?

Comment: @wibeasley have never used dput() function and I have no clue what it is. the example given in the package pdf is 


#fit two-part model with different regressors in both parts(This is formula i used for the 2 part regression)

 tpmodel = tpm(formula_part1 = exp_tot~female+age, formula_part2 = exp_tot~female+age+ed_colplus,data = meps,link_part1 = "logit", family_part2 = Gamma(link = "log"))

 tpmodel

 summary(tpmodel)


 ##Predictive margins and corresponding ratios for all variables with ##standard errors and CIs.
 margin(tpmodel)

Comment: "...I have no clue what it is".  I understand.  The post I referenced explains `dput()` and other strategies to receive helpful responses on SO.